# How to Call a Function with a Parameter in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I am working with Blazor. I am learning this framework but I have got a problem. I can call a JavaScript function but when I call a C# function I get this error:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line   Suppression State
>   Error CS0411  The type arguments for method
>   'RuntimeHelpers.CreateInferredEventCallback(object, Action, T)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

I use Radzen and this my code block:

```
<td>
<RadzenDropDown AllowClear="true" @bind-Value="(() => MultipleGetUser(item.UserID))" Multiple="true" Placeholder="Select..." Data="@UserList" TextProperty="UserName" ValueProperty="UserID" Change="@(args => ChangeUser(args, ""))" />
</td>
```

This error in **"@bind-Value"**. How call a function with a parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot bind to function only field or property are allowed.
@bind- means it's bidirectional, so you need something you can set.
However you can create a computed property:

```cs
...
<td>
<RadzenDropDown AllowClear="true" @bind-Value="@this[item.UserID]" Multiple="true" Placeholder="Select..." Data="@UserList" TextProperty="UserName" ValueProperty="UserID" Change="@(args => ChangeUser(args, ""))" />
</td>
...
@code {
     User this[int id] // I assume you have a User class, replace by the one you use
     {
         get => MultipleGetUser(id);
         set => // as I don't how you can set your user by its Id I let you implement this code
     }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, when I try create class ad you but I take error on int and get, set. "Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type."

Comment: oups, my bad, I lost my C#

Comment: I don't a error when change it. But, I when run app; I take this error: "Invalid expression term '[' ".
"

Comment: try @this[item.UserID]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and information. That's work.