# How to call a method in Blazor Server Side App on get set of a parameter

Tags: c#, data-binding, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a select control bound to a selected value.  Since I can't use @onChange and @bind at the same time, what's the @bind version of:

```
<select @onchange='(e  => DisplayToggle(e, "DMGReported"))' class="form-control">
    <option value=" "> </option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

Which executes:

```
async Task DisplayToggle(ChangeEventArgs e, string DivToToggle)
{
    selectedString = e.Value.ToString();
    //Do something with that selected value
}
```

Using OnParamterSet(), it fires once...but won't go again if the selected option in the dropdown is changed.  Trying to call a method inside the get/set of the parameter causes the page to get a stack overflow with a repeat in the thousands.  I tried that after I stumbled across this:

[How to Call a Function with a Parameter in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62150809/how-to-call-a-function-with-a-parameter-in-blazor)

[image]

```
<select @bind="selectedString">
   <option value=" "> </option>
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
   <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
<p>@className</p>
string className = "";

public string selectedString
{
    get => Test(selectedString);
    set { selectedString = value; }

}

public string Test(string test)
{
   
        if (selectedString == "Yes")
        {
            className = "It worked";
        }
        else
        {
            className = "It Failed";
        }
        
    return test;
}
```

Functional Code thanks to the help from Brian Parker:
Weirdly enough, this has to be on the page:

```
<p style="display:none;">@dmgReported</p>
```

For this to work:

```
string selectedString;
string dmgReported => packageSubmission.RepDmg switch
{
    "Yes" => ToggleDiv("Yes", "DMGNotReported", "DMGReported"),
    "No" => ToggleDiv("No", "DMGReported", "DMGNotReported"),
    _ => ToggleDiv("", "DMGReported", "DMGNotReported")
};
public string ToggleDiv(string YesNo, string DivToHide, string DivToShow)
{
    try
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(packageSubmission.RepDmg))
        {
            if (YesNo == "No" || YesNo == "Yes")
            {
                JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("hideElement", new { id = DivToHide });
                JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("showGroup", new { id = DivToShow });
            }               
            else
            {
                JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("hideElement", new { id = DivToHide });
                JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("hideElement", new { id = DivToShow });
            }
        }
    }
    catch { }
    return DivToHide;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have to use a setter. Just a computed property based on the bind value.

```
<select @bind="selectedString">
   <option value=" "> </option>
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
   <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

<p>@className</p>

@code {
   string selectedString;
   string className => selectedString switch 
   {
       "Yes" => "It worked",
       "No" => "It failed",
       _ => ""
   };
}
```

[BlazorRepl](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/mPEgEjvx50HxkQzh01)

If you need to use the setter :

```
<select @bind="SelectedString">
   <option value=" "> </option>
   <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
   <option value="No">No</option>
</select>

<p>@className</p>
@code {
   string className;
   string selectedString;
   string SelectedString 
   {
       get => selectedString;
       set 
       {
            if(selectedString == value) return; // Do nothing
            selectedString = value;
            className = value switch 
            {
                "Yes" => "It worked",
                "No" => "It failed",
                _ => ""                
            };        
       }
   }
}
```

[BlazorRepl](https://blazorrepl.com/repl/QbuUkZPx49gdtkTK06)

Comment: Thank you for getting me in the right direction.  Updating my post to reflect the answer with the method call included.